# Typescript intellisense fails to calculate proper type ans use "any" instead

Tags: typescript

I'm implementing a service with generics in TypeScript, but when I try to retrieve an element which type is a property of generic, I get suggested `any` and not the proper type.

Here is the code:

```
export class NavigatorService<T extends NavigationPage> {
    async get(page: T): Promise<T["params"]> {
        // some code..
        return currentPage.params;
    }
}

@Injectable()
// HERE THE TYPE IS DEFINED
export class A1NavigatorService extends NavigatorService<A1> {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

export type Page = EsitoAcquisto;

class NavigationPage {
    public url: string;
    public name: string;
    public params: any;
    public toString(): string {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}


export class A1 extends NavigationPage {
    public url = '';
    public name = '[A1]';
    public params = null;


    constructor(params?: A1Params) {
        super();
        this.params = params || null;
    }
}


interface A1Params {
    name: string;
}
```

I expect that `A1NavigatorService.get()` returns a `Promise` of `A1Params`, since TypeScript has all the information for the forecast.

`A1NavigatorService` extends `NavigatorService` using `A1` as generic type. So `T` is `A1` and `A1["params"]` type is `A1Params`.

But when I try:

```
A1NavigatorService.get().then(el => {

})
```

`el`'s type is `any`.

I also tried:

```
A1NavigatorService.get(new A1()).then(el => {

})
```

So it's easier to assign `A1` to `T`'s type for the engine, but it doesn't work, producing the same effect.

What is wrong here? How can I achieve the same result?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved faster than I thought, I just needed to add a definition also in the class property and not only in the constructor:

```
export class A1 extends NavigationPage {
    public url = '';
    public name = '[A1]';
    public params: A1Params = null;
```

Comment: Or you just omit the field declaration.

Comment: Uhm no, in that case it complains since I don't call super immediately

Comment: What exactly did you try?